# Why is class.__weakref__ not None, while instance.__weakref__ is None?

Tags: python, weak-references, python-internals

`__weakref__` is related to weak references. I get the whole idea behind weak references and where I might use them. The only thing that I don't get is described in the following:

An instance doesn't have the attribute `__weakref__` itself, distinct from the class, therefore the instance *inherits* `__weakref__` from the class, this means that `A.__weakref__` should be the same as  `A().__weakref__`:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> A().__dict__            # Each instance starts out as an empty namespace 
{}
>>> A.__weakref__ is None; 
False
>>> A().__weakref__ is None   #But this is True!
True
```

Why is `A.__weakref__` not `None` while `instance.__weakref__` is `None` although instances inherit `__weakref__` from the class?

Comment: *"this means that `A.__weakref__` is the same as `A().__weakref__`"* - clearly not, so your assumption that *"instances inherit `__weakref__` from the class"* is incorrect. `A.__weakref__ is A().__weakref__` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class has a `__weakref__` [*data descriptor* attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); this acts just like a `property`; only when you access the attribute on an instance is it automatically bound. The actual data for a weak reference is stored in a C structure, part of the data structure Python uses to represent classes and instances in memory.

As such, instances don't need their own `__weakref__` attribute. The class descriptor is bound to the instance data structure, and the C code then just looks in the right C struct to retrieve the information needed.

Accessing the attribute on the class, produces the descriptor object itself. This is not `None`; it is the descriptor object. On an instance, the bound attribute produces the weak reference. No weak reference means `None` is returned.

You can re-create the descriptor behaviour by accessing the object via `A.__dict__['__weakref__']` (to bypass the normal `type.__getattribute__()` binding behaviour), then directly calling `__get__` on that:

```
>>> import weakref
>>> class A(object): pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> A.__weakref__
<attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>
>>> descriptor = A.__dict__['__weakref__']
>>> descriptor.__get__(None, A)
<attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__weakref__ is None
True
>>> descriptor.__get__(a) is None
True
>>> wr = weakref.ref(a)  # add a weak reference
>>> wr
<weakref at 0x10bd86d68; to 'A' at 0x10bad3588>
>>> a.__weakref__
<weakref at 0x10bd86d68; to 'A' at 0x10bad3588>
>>> descriptor.__get__(a)
<weakref at 0x10bd86d68; to 'A' at 0x10bad3588>
```

Comment: Can I ask why did you mention : *"to bypass the normal `type.__getattribute__()` binding behaviour"* ? I can see that `print(A.__weakref__ is A.__dict__["__weakref__"])` is True. I mean isn't `__weakref__` a class attribute which happens to be a decsriptor in the class's namespace?  Does `type` metaclass do something in it's `__getattribute__` method for `"__weakref__"` key?